# Interesting Proofs about Metric Spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, soft-question

I'm currently working through the book *Introduction to Topology* by Bert Mendelson, and I've finished all of the exercises provided at the end of the section that I have just completed, but I would like some more to try. I've just finished learning about metric spaces, continuity, and open balls about points in metric spaces. Just for a bit of context, some of the proofs that I have done include:

> - If $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $a\in X$, for each $\delta \gt 0$, the open ball $B(a; \delta)$ is a neighborhood of each of its points.
> - Let $f:(X,d)\to (Y,d')$, $a\in X$, and let $\beta_{f(a)}$ be a basis for the neighborhood system at $f(a)$. Prove that $f$ is continuous at $a$ iff $f^{-1}(N)$ is a neighborhood of $a$ for each $N \in \beta_{f(a)}$.
> - If $a$ and $b$ are distinct points of a metric space $X$, prove that there exist neighborhoods $N_a$ and $N_b$ of $a$ and $b$ respectively such that $N_a \cap N_b=\varnothing$.
> - If $(X,d)$ is a metric space containing $a$ and $b$, and $\delta+\eta \lt d(a,b)$, then $B(a;\delta)\cap B(b;\eta)=\varnothing$.

Can anybody give me any other (perhaps slightly more challenging) proofs to do about these topics? I would like to practice some more with them, but I'm not very good about forming true conjectures to prove.

Thanks!

Comment: Have yoy learned about closures of sets in a metric space ,compactness ,sequences and completness?

Comment: @RamizKaraeski No, not yet. But I'm getting there! :D

Comment: General advice. Whenever you prove a theorem, try to see what happens if you weaken the hypotheses - look for a counterexample or try to get away with assuming less.

Comment: @EthanBolker Ooh, interesting idea...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$1)$Prove or disprove with a counterxample:
 Is a countable intersection of open sets always open?

$2)$Prove that a finite intersection of open sets is open.

$3)$Let  the space $C[0,1]=\{f[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}|f$ continuous on $[0,1]\}$ and $d(f,g)= \int_0^1|f(x)-g(x)|dx$. Prove that $d$ is a metric.

$4)$Let (X,d) be a metric space.Prove that the collection of sets $T=\{A \subseteq X| \forall x \in A,\exists \epsilon>0$such that $B(x, \epsilon) \subseteq A\}$ is a topology on $X$.You need only to look the definition of a topolgy to solve this.

$5)$ Prove that the set of rational numbers is not an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ under the metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$(usual metric)

$6)$Prove that the set  $A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2|x+y>1\}$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ under the metric $d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$

$7)$Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A \subset X$.We define $(x_0,A)=\inf\{d(x_0,y)|y \in A \}$. This quantity is called the distance between $x_0$ and $A$.Prove that the function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=d(x,A)$ is lipschitz continuous.

$8)$A set $A$ in a metric (and topological in general)space is closed  if $X$ \ $A$ is open.
Prove that the set $\mathbb{Z}$ is a closed subsets of the real line under the usual metric.Also prove that the set of rational numbers in not closed under the same metric.

$9)$A subset $Y$ of metric space X is connected if there DO NOT exist two open sets  $A,B \subseteq X$ such that $Y=A \cup B$ and $A \cap B= \emptyset$.
Prove that the set $(0,1)$ is a connected subset of $ \mathbb{R}$ under the usual metric.Also prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not connected in $\mathbb{R}$ under the usual metric.

$10)$Firstly prove that an interval $(a,b),(a, + \infty),(- \infty,a)$($0<a<b$) are open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ under the usual metric ($d(x,y)=|x-y|$)

Secondly prove that the set $[a,b]$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$(use the definition of a previous exercise and the first part of the exercise)

Finally, prove that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [1+\frac{1}{n},2-\frac{1}{n}]=(1,2)$

This is an example in which an infinite union of closed sets in a metric space need not to be a closed set.

$11)$Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space .We define the diameter of a set $A$ as $diam(A)=\sup \{d(x,y)|x,y \in A\}$.Suppose that $B$ is a bounded subset of X and  $C \subseteq B$.Prove that $diam(C) \leqslant diam(B)$

$12)$Let $X$ be the space of continuous functions on $[0, 1]$($C[0,1]$) with the metric $d(f,g)= \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|$.Show that $d$ is indeed a metric.
Also show that the subset 
$A = \{f ∈ X | f(x) > 1,$ for $x \in [1/3, 2/3]\}$ is open in $X$.

$13)$Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.Define $A+B=\{x+y|x \in A ,y \in B \}$ and $x+A=\{x+y| y \in A\}$ where $A,B \subseteq X$.Prove that if $A,B$ are open sets then $A+B,x+A$ are also open sets.

$14)$Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.A sequence $x_n \in X$ converges to $x$ if $\forall \epsilon >0 ,\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(x_n,x)< \epsilon, \forall n \geqslant n_0$.Consider the space $(\mathbb{R}^m,d)$ with the euclideian metric.Prove that $x_n \rightarrow x=(x_1,x_2...x_m)$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ if and only if $x_n^j \rightarrow x_j \in \mathbb{R}, \forall j \in \{1,2...m\}$(A sequence in $\mathbb{R}^m$ has the form $x_n=(x_n^1,x_n^2...x_n^m))$

$15)$Let a function  $f:(X,d_1) \rightarrow (Y,d_2)$.Prove that $f$ is continuous in $X$ if and only if for every sequence $x_n \rightarrow x$ in $X$ we have $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$ in $Y$.

I hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: Where are these questions from? If they are from a book or other source, the source should be mentioned. If there is no source and you just came up with these, I think it would be appropriate to tell us much.

Comment: i came up with  some of these questions and the other questions where given by my proffesor to solve way back when i was attending a topology course.in conclusio these are some exercises i solved and i remembered and i choosed them for the O.P because they can be solved with the knowledge the O.P has learned so far (and  mentions in his post).To help the O.P i also gave the appropriate  definintions  of some consepts used in the exercises.

Comment: .It would be helpfull for the O.P to be introduced and to work with new consepts  in these exercises and in exercises in general.

Answer (score 5):

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.

- If $f:(X,d)\to (X,d)$ is continuous and $f\circ f=f$ then $f(X)$ is closed.
- Every sequence in $(X,d)$ converges to at most one point in $X$.
- For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists a metric $\rho$ on $X$ such that for each $x,y\in X, \rho(x,y)\leq n$ and the family of open balls in $(X,d)$ coincides with the family of open balls in $(X,\rho)$.
- If $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $d$ is the usual metric then every closed interval (or in fact any closed set) is the intersection of a family of open sets, i.e. a $G_\delta$ set.
- Every point of $X$ has a countable neighborhood base, i.e. for each $x\in X,$ there exists a countable family $\eta(x)$ of open sets such that for any open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there exists $V\in \eta(x)$ such that $x\in U\subseteq V$.
- If $(X,d)$ is second countable, i.e. if there exists a countable family $\mathcal{B}$ of open sets in $(X,d)$ such that for each open set $U$ in $X$, there exists an open set $V\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $V\subseteq U$, then $(X,d)$ is first countable but the converse is not necessarily true.
- If $E,F$ are two disjoint closed subsets of $X$ then there exist disjoint $U,V$ open sets in $(X,d)$ such that $E\subseteq U,\ F\subseteq V$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$.
- If $a\in X$ and $F$ is a closed subset of $X$ with $x\notin F$ then there exists $U, V$ open subsets of $X$ such that $x\in U,\ F\subseteq V$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$.
- If $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $d$ is the usual metric then every open subset of $X$ is at most a countable union of disjoint open intervals.

Comment: $(X,d)$ is actually *always* first countable.

Comment: Where are these questions from? If they are from a book or other source, the source should be mentioned. If there is no source and you just came up with these, I think it would be appropriate to tell us much.

Comment: Well most of the questions posed here are rather "theorems" that I was given (to prove as exercises) when I was learning topology at university and I just typed them here by memory. Please check again that all these are "standard results". For example, I think the first question is a special case of "Retract of a Hausdorff space is closed", and the ones before the last are about the normality and regularity of metric spaces. There is nothing original in this problems list.

Answer (score 4):

The "discrete metric" on a space $X$ is one in which $d(x, y) = 1$ if $x \ne y$, and $d(x, x) = 0$.

(a) Show that for any set $X$, the discrete metric on $X$ is, in fact, a metric.

(b) Show that every function from $X$ with its discrete metric to any metric space $Y$ is in fact continuous.

(c) Show that a continuous function from any metric space $Y$ to the space $X$ (with its discrete metric) must be constant.

Comment: Uh...no. For instance, the unique map from $\{0, 1\{\}$ with its usual topology to $\{0\}$ is constant, and continuous, but the domain is not connected.

Answer (score 3):

(1.1). Show that if $F$ is a family of subsets of a metric space such that $\cup G$ is closed whenever $G$ is a countable subset of $F$ , then $\cup F$ is closed.

(2). Different metrics that generate the same topology are called equivalent metrics:

(2.1). Show that if $d,e$ are equivalent metrics on  $X$    iff for every $r>0$ and every $x\in X$ there exist $r'>0$ and $r''>0$ such that $B_d(x,r')\subset B_e(x,r)$ and $B_e(x,r'')\subset B_d(x,r).$

(2.2). Let $d,e$ be metrics on $X$ such that there exist positive $k,k'$ such that $d(u,v)\leq k\cdot e(u,v)$ and $e(u,v)\leq k'\cdot d(u,v)$ for all $u,v \in X.$ Show that  $d,e$ are equivalent. (If such $k,k'$ exist then $d,e$ are called uniformly equivalent). And give an example of two equivalent metrics that are not uniformly equivalent.

(2.2).  For a  metric $d,$ show that $e_1=d/(1+d)$ and $e_2=\min (1,d)$  are metrics and are  equivalent to $d.$

(2.3). Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,e)$ be metric spaces and let  $f:X\to Y$ be continuous. Show that $$f(u,v)=d(u,v)+e(f(u),f(v)) \quad \text {for } u,v\in X$$ is a metric on $X$ equivalent to $d.$ (In particular, with $Y=\mathbb R$ and $e(y,y')=|y-y'|,$ this is useful in constructions for other problems and examples.)

(3). Sequences and closures:

(3.1). In a metric space $(X,d)$ with $x\in X,$ show that a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ of members of $X$ satisfies $\lim_{n\to \infty}d(x,x_n)=0$ iff $\{n\in \mathbb N: d(x_n,x)\geq r\}$ is finite for every $r>0.$

(3.2). Show that if $\lim_{n\to \infty} d(x,x_n)=0=\lim_{n\to \infty}d(x,x'_n)$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}d(x_n,x'_n)=0.$

(3.3). For metric space $(X,d)$ and $Y\subset X ,$ define $\overline Y$ to be the set of all ,and only those, $x\in X$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}d(x,y_n)=0$ for some sequence $(y_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ of members of $Y.$ Prove that $$\overline {(\overline Y)}=\overline Y.$$

Answer (score 2):

- Every convergent sequence is bounded.
- The closure of an open ball $B(a;\delta)$ is a subset of the closed ball centered at $a$ with radius $\delta$.
- The union of a sequence of closed subsets doesn't have to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of really good metric problems have already been posted, but I'd like to add that you may want to try *Topology Without Tears* by Sidney A. Morris. The book is extremely rigorous and has hundreds of problems at varying difficulties; as with a lot of proofs, some take seconds, some might take you days.